# Fastapi Depends in query parameter is ignored

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a fastapi app with a query dependency for validation

```py
async def parse_uuids(uuids: str) -> list[UUID]:
    try:
        return [UUID(uuids)]
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return [UUID(uuid_) for uuid_ in uuids.split(",")]
        except ValueError:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid UUID format")

@list_router.get(path="/activities", response_model=ActivitySchema)
async def get_activities(
    in_ids: Annotated[
        list[str] | None,
        Depends(parse_uuids),
        Query(
            alias="id",
            description='Must be UUID or comma separated UUIDs'
        )
    ] = None
) -> Any:
    pass
```

I can call `GET /activities?id=` with any kind of string whatsoever, the dependency is completely ignored and no error is raised.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `Depends()` with `Query()` inside one field, resulting in unexpected behaviour (because of recent migration to Pydantic v2.0, those things are allowed to be and are not forbidden by FastAPI yet). You should remove `Query()` from your route handler and place it directly inside `parse_uuids()`:

```
async def parse_uuids(uuids: Annotated[str, Query(alias="id")]) -> list[UUID]:
    ...
```